# WPF Submenu styling

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, menuitem, styling

If I add a submenu to a menu item, then the submenu is not being styled properly.  One can only style the menuitem at this point, and not the actual sub menu. Hence one can't replace the `IsMouseOver` styling which then just defaults to whatever theme is enabled on windows.

How can one style the submenu?

---

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0f3c5a"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
                    
                    <!--Here is where you change the border thickness to zero on the menu-->
                    <Border BorderThickness="0" x:Name="Border"  >
                     <StackPanel ClipToBounds="True" Orientation="Vertical"
                     IsItemsHost="True"/>
                     </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#5082a4" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
```

and then something like this for the menu

```
<ContextMenu Closed="ContextMenu_Closed"  >
    <MenuItem  Command="k:Window1.NewCommand" > 
       <MenuItem  Command="k:Window1.DeleteCommand"/> 
    </MenuItem>
    ...
```

Everything on the NewCommand layer is styled properly, going inside NewCommand to view DeleteCommand the MenuItem itself is styled properly, but the actual menu is defaulting to the Windows theme styling and I see no way over overwriting that so far.  The most important part is to get the IsMouseOver of submenu's to maintain the same look and feel as the main menu structure.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As promised, here's the code.  Thanks for your help Jay, lead me in the right direction to finally find an answer on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752296.aspx MenuItem and ContextMenu control the styling for the base menu, and the other two are for the submenu items.  Jay's way may have worked, but I couldn't get it to unfortunately.  This works perfectly though, and probably allows for much more control over the submenus styling.

```
    <UserControl.Resources>

    <!-- Separator -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Separator}"
           x:Key="SeparatorStyle">
        <Setter Property="Height"
                Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="#0f3c5a" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
                    <Rectangle Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                               Fill="White" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <!--Outer menu items-->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="#0f3c5a"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="White"></Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted"
                     Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="Black"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                     Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="LightGray"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <!-- Outer menu -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
                Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
                Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">

                    <!--Here is where you change the border thickness to zero on the menu-->
                    <Border BorderThickness="0"
                            x:Name="Border"
                            Background="Transparent">
                        <StackPanel ClipToBounds="True"
                                    Orientation="Vertical"
                                    IsItemsHost="True" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                 Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border"
                                    Property="Background"
                                    Value="#0f3c5a" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <!-- SubmenuItem -->

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuItemTemplateKey}"
                     TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Border Name="Border">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                                      SharedSizeGroup="Icon" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                                      SharedSizeGroup="Shortcut" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="13" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter Name="Icon"
                                  Margin="6,0,6,0"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  ContentSource="Icon" />
                <Border Name="Check"
                        Width="13"
                        Height="13"
                        Visibility="Collapsed"
                        Margin="6,0,6,0"
                        Background="#0f3c5a"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        BorderBrush="#5082a4">
                    <Path Name="CheckMark"
                          Width="7"
                          Height="7"
                          Visibility="Hidden"
                          SnapsToDevicePixels="False"
                          Stroke="#5082a4"
                          StrokeThickness="2"
                          Data="M 0 0 L 7 7 M 0 7 L 7 0" />
                </Border>
                <ContentPresenter Name="HeaderHost"
                                  Grid.Column="1"
                                  ContentSource="Header"
                                  RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="InputGestureText"
                           Grid.Column="2"
                           Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}"
                           Margin="5,2,0,2"
                           DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Icon"
                     Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter TargetName="Icon"
                        Property="Visibility"
                        Value="Hidden" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                     Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="CheckMark"
                        Property="Visibility"
                        Value="Visible" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsCheckable"
                     Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Check"
                        Property="Visibility"
                        Value="Visible" />
                <Setter TargetName="Icon"
                        Property="Visibility"
                        Value="Hidden" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted"
                     Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Border"
                        Property="Background"
                        Value="#5082a4" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                     Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="#0f3c5a" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <!-- SubmenuHeader -->

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey}"
                     TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Border Name="Border">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                                      SharedSizeGroup="Icon" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                                      SharedSizeGroup="Shortcut" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="13" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter Name="Icon"
                                  Margin="6,0,6,0"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  ContentSource="Icon" />
                <ContentPresenter Name="HeaderHost"
                                  Grid.Column="1"
                                  ContentSource="Header"
                                  RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="InputGestureText"
                           Grid.Column="2"
                           Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}"
                           Margin="5,2,2,2"
                           DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
                <Path Grid.Column="3"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      Data="M 0 0 L 0 7 L 4 3.5 Z"
                      Fill="#0f3c5a" />
                <Popup Name="Popup"
                       Placement="Right"
                       HorizontalOffset="-4"
                       IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}"
                       AllowsTransparency="True"
                       Focusable="False"
                       PopupAnimation="Fade">
                    <Border Name="SubmenuBorder"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                            Background="#0f3c5a"
                            BorderBrush="#0f3c5a"
                            BorderThickness="1">
                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                                    KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
        </Border>

        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Icon"
                     Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter TargetName="Icon"
                        Property="Visibility"
                        Value="Collapsed" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted"
                     Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Border"
                        Property="Background"
                        Value="#5082a4" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger SourceName="Popup"
                     Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency"
                     Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder"
                        Property="CornerRadius"
                        Value="4" />
                <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder"
                        Property="Padding"
                        Value="0,3,0,3" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                     Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="#0f3c5a" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting it; don't forget to mark it as the answer.

Comment: @Jay, I still have 53 minutes till Stackoverflow lets me mark my own answer :-P

Answer (score 1):

How are you applying your styles?

Typically, if you define as style in a "high" or "outer" element's Resources, and give it no key, it will apply to all items of the target type below.

Are you doing this and seeing unexpected behaviour, or are you attempting to define/apply styles in-line at each level?

#### edit 1

Looking at your XAML, I think the issue is that you are styling `ContextMenu`, but menus below that are of type `Menu`. The first thing I'd try is to just change the `TargetType` attribute for the `Style` to `Menu`. See if that gets applied at all levels. If not, I'd change it back and add another `Style` targeting `Menu` and see if *that* one gets applied to the submenu.

#### edit 2

Okay, I think I've got your answer. The submenu is actually a `MenuItem`, which is obvious when looking at the XAML instead of the result. The template and styling that you're setting on the `ContextMenu` must also be set on any `MenuItem` that is a submenu. I tried it out and created a style that targets `MenuItem` with a control template and trigger for `IsMouseOver` and it appeared to do what you're trying.

Comment: Jay, that didn't fix anything, the sub-menu didn't take the style.  This is a very odd problem.

Comment: Jay, not really sure what you did to make yours work, but when I tried that it didn't do anything.  However, your post did help me find the right answer finally!  I'll post the code in a new answer shortly, just cleaning it up some.

Answer (score 0):

To not duplicate the templates, you're better off creating one with both PART_Popup and arrow for the submenu, but hide the error until you're triggered with Role being SubmenuHeader.